# TYPO3: User Permissions: Allow to hide Plugin Content Element

Tags: permissions, typo3, typo3-9.x

Is it possible to allow a backend user to show/hide a type of plugin (e.g. News) - but not to edit/delete it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible as the hiding is no separate right.
visibility is handled as a field like many others.

Additionally: plugins are a very special kind of content. 
in general all plugins are one kind of content element with further specification which plugin it is.

trying to remove the option to edit all fields except `hidden` and only for one kind of plugin you first need a selection for this plugin:
`cType = 'list' && list_type = 'my_plugin'`

Then you could remove access to all fields except `hidden`, but how would you identify the plugin? 'no access' means: you don't see it.
'It is the content element where you only see the existence' ?

---

Maybe there are other options for your intention, but that would need further information.

e.g.:
BE-module to switch visibility,
global flag for this plugin,
switch pages with/without plugin,
:

Comment: thank you Bernd, the identification is not an issue - for me it would be ok to treat all content elements the same way - allow to hide but not to edit/delete.